# Is blazor `dotnet publish` hard-coded to `web.config` and the `wwwroot` folder for WebAssembly standalone deployment or am i missing out on the docs?

Tags: asp.net, blazor

Yes, I see that `dotnet publish` has an `--output` parameter but the conventional `wwwroot` directory (with a `web.config` in a parent directory) will be appended; is there a way to stop this from happening to recognize non-IIS/non-Kudu environments?

There are docs like “[Host ASP.NET Core on Linux with Apache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-7.0)” that make no mention of the `wwwroot` convention. There are sections in official documentation, like “[Standalone deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-5.0#standalone-deployment),” that leave truisms like:

> Standalone deployment assets are published into the `/bin/Release/{TARGET FRAMEWORK}/publish/wwwroot` folder.

…but make no mention of how to change this `wwwroot` convention. Is this convention hard-coded or is there a wonderful way to change this?